# Java SWT: removeAll() in TABLE doesn't delete my buttons on the rows

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I have a Table with 4 columns, and the fourth is filled with buttons with CHECK style.

The problem is that every time I do a removeAll() for fill the table with other content, the buttons are not being deleted, so I can see the same buttons with the same status in the same rows.

This is my table:

```
Table membersTable = new Table(clubComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
membersTable.setLinesVisible(true);
membersTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
membersTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

TableColumn tblclmnName = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnName.setWidth(150);
tblclmnName.setText("Nombre");

TableColumn tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setWidth(120);
tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setText("Teléfono");

TableColumn tblclmnCommonMoney = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnCommonMoney.setWidth(150);
tblclmnCommonMoney.setText("Participación Habitual");

TableColumn tblclmnPayed = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.CENTER);
tblclmnPayed.setWidth(50);
tblclmnPayed.setText("Payed");
```

And this is the way I'm populating the table, also you can see the buttons:

```
// populate Table
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(membersTable, SWT.NONE);                    
    tableItem.setText(new String[] {"person "+i, "610610620", "100"});

    Button button = new Button(membersTable, SWT.CHECK);
    button.pack();
    TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(membersTable);
    editor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
    editor.setEditor(button, tableItem, 3);

    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //how to know in which row is clicked the checkbox?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TableEditor` is not a `TableItem` and will not be removed by `removeAll` (neither by `clearAll`).

The corresponding controls can be disposed programmatically, like in:

```
membersTable.removeAll();
Arrays.stream(membersTable.getChildren())    // stream over all children
      .filter(Button.class::isInstance)      // only the Buttons
      .forEach(Control::dispose);            // and dispose it
```

or (same as above)

```
membersTable.removeAll();
for(Control control : membersTable.getChildren()) {
    if (control instanceof Button) {
        control.dispose();
    }
}
```

Alternative, save the `TableEditor`s in a list and dispose theirs editors:

```
List<TableEditor> editors = new ArrayList<>();
...
membersTable.removeAll();
editors.stream()                      // stream over TableEditors
       .map(TableEditor::getEditor)   // get their Editor (a Control)
       .forEach(Control::dispose);    // dispose it
editors.clear();
```